# Xamarin Bindable property not binding

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been trying to make this small demo app, that is basically a timer with storable time intervals. I dislike the timepicker controls that are used in the android version so I decided to make my own custom control (using ContentView instead of a custom renderer) to group three pickers for hours, minutes and seconds and update a single TimeSpan object.

My goal is to have a ContentView that is used to represent TimeSpan as parts of a ListView cell, [here is how it looks for a better understanding.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG8dN.png) Problem is I can't seem to get the binding to work proprely. As shown in the image all values are zero, though in this mock option the should all have minute values set. Instead they are all set to zero, and as much as I check they also don't set back all the way back to the model.

As it's supposed to work is when the user selects a value in on of the fields on the right --> it should set the boud property string in the view model --> which should update the value of the TimeSpan property --> which should update the model. And the other way should look like: the list view item gets rendered --> the value of the TimeSpan property is bound --> this sets the value in the viewmodel --> this updates the model.

I'll admit I'm a bit fuzzy on how exactly the end value in the ViewModel is actually bound to the custom control (as the other way would seem to need to work when calling propertyChanged callback).

TimeSpanPropertyChanged and the TimeSpan accessors don't seem to be called after the initial values are set (break point doesn't trigger), unless I use a static value (like "1" instead of "(Binding Duration)" which is the property name in the model). The data returned from the mock service is correct up to and including the creation of PresetViewModel objects.

**PresetsPage.xaml**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Intervals}" SelectionMode="None">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    
                                    <controls:CustomTimeOffsetSelector  TimeSpan="{Binding Duration}"  Grid.Column="1"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <ListView.Footer>
                        <Button Text="Add interval"/>
                    </ListView.Footer>
                </ListView>
```

It's values are bound to the view model

**PresetViewModel.cs**

```
public class PresetViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Interval> intervals;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (o, e) => { };
    public Preset Data { get; private set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get => Data.Name;
        set
        {
            Data.Name = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Interval> Intervals
    {
        get => intervals;            
        set
        {
            intervals = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Intervals"));
        }
    }

    public PresetViewModel(Preset preset)
    {
        Data = preset;
        Intervals = new ObservableCollection<Interval>(Data.Intervals);
    }
//...
}
```

The Custom control looks like:

**CustomTimeOffsetSelector.xaml**

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App2.Controls.CustomTimeOffsetSelector">
  <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Picker  ItemsSource="{Binding HourList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Hours}"/>
            <Label Text=":" FontSize="Small" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
            <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding MinuteList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Minutes}"/>
            <Label Text=":" FontSize="Small" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
            <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding SecondList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Seconds}"/>
        </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**CustomTimeOffsetSelector.xaml.cs**

```
 [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class CustomTimeOffsetSelector : ContentView
    {

        public static readonly BindableProperty TimeSpanProperty = 
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(TimeSpan),
                typeof(TimeSpan),
                typeof(CustomTimeOffsetSelector),
                defaultValue: TimeSpan.Zero,
                defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
                propertyChanged: TimeSpanPropertyChanged
            );

        private static void TimeSpanPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var control = bindable as CustomTimeOffsetSelector;
            control.viewModel.Data = (TimeSpan)newValue;
        }

        public TimeSpan TimeSpan 
        {
            get => (TimeSpan)GetValue(TimeSpanProperty);
            set => SetValue(TimeSpanProperty, value); 
        }

        IntervalViewModel viewModel; 

        public CustomTimeOffsetSelector()
        {
            viewModel = new IntervalViewModel();
            BindingContext = viewModel;

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

And finaly the view model.
**IntervalViewModel.cs**

```
public class IntervalViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        #region List init area
        private static List<string> hourValues;
    public static List<string> HourValues
    {
        get
        {
            if (hourValues == null)
            {
                hourValues = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
                    hourValues.Add(i.ToString("00"));
            }

            return hourValues;
        }
    }

    private static List<string> minuteValues;
    public static List<string> MinuteValues
    {
        get
        {
            if (minuteValues == null)
            {
                minuteValues = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
                    minuteValues.Add(i.ToString("00"));
            }

            return minuteValues;
        }
    }

    private static List<string> secondValues;
    public static List<string> SecondValues
    {
        get
        {
            if (secondValues == null)
            {
                secondValues = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
                    secondValues.Add(i.ToString("00"));
            }

            return secondValues;
        }
    }

    public List<string> HourList => HourValues;
    public List<string> MinuteList => MinuteValues;
    public List<string> SecondList => SecondValues;
        #endregion

        private TimeSpan data;

        public  TimeSpan Data
        {
            get =>  data;
            set
            {
                data = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Hours"));
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Minutes"));
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Seconds"));
            }
        }
  
        public string Hours
        {
            get
            {
                return data.Hours.ToString("00");
            }
            set
            {
                data = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(value), data.Minutes, data.Seconds);
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Hours"));
            }
        }
        public string Minutes
        {
            get
            {
                return data.Minutes.ToString("00");
            }
            set
            {
                data = new TimeSpan(data.Hours, int.Parse(value), data.Seconds);
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Minutes"));
            }
        }
        public string Seconds
        {
            get
            {
                return data.Seconds.ToString("00");
            }
            set
            {
                data = new TimeSpan(data.Hours, data.Minutes, int.Parse(value));
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Seconds"));

            }
        }

        public IntervalViewModel()
        {

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

**Interval.cs**

```
public class Interval
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
    }
```

I know some of the names of files and properties are not the best ones, as well as that using a base ViewModel class would make evrything cleaner my intention was to refactor after I get it working.

I've just been staring at this issue for the last two days and can't seem to think of anything and the answers I find seem to give similar code to what I have currently, which so far has not worked. I'd really appreciate any help in the matter - thank you.

Comment: where is the code for `Interval`?

Comment: @Jason 
Oh sorry, forgot that one. Added it in, but it is a pretty generic model class with a few properties, that's it.

Comment: Where are `HourList` ,`MinuteList` and `SecondList` defined ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT They are just stimple string lists to populate the pickers, that get parsed on the set methods, so I removed them from here, seemed like extra clutter, that doesn't change much. Added them back in IntervalViewModel if that makes any difference. They populate and set Hours, Minutes and Seconds properties successfully, even update the IntervalViewModel.data member.

Comment: Any solutions for this?